# AdMob on Windows Phone 7 - this is possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, admob

At present, official "Google Mobile Ads SDK" is supports only Windows Phone 8:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadwp

Is it any solution to show ads on Windows Phone 7?

Comment: you can try [Ad Rotator](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/). It supports multiple ads platforms, including AdMob : [getting started tutorial](http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/would-you-like-ads-with-thatintro-to-adrotator-for-wp7/)

Comment: unfortunately AdMob+AdRotator don't work on WP7

Answer (score 0):

Google deprecated Windows Phone 7 in August 2013 : https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3369601?hl=en-GB

Ad Rotator comes with the libraries that supported Windows Phone 7, though whether you will be able to create new Ads through the AdMob site that target Windows Phone 7 and the old SDK is another matter, pretty sure it's currently Windows Phone 8 only.